# Función change, al pulsar y al soltar

Tags: php, javascript, html

¿Existe la posibilidad de hacer que cuando el `input` este marcado realice una acción y cuando pulse de nuevo para desmarcarlo realice otra acción?

Para detallarlo, tengo un conjunto de `inputs checkbox`. Según pulso a cada uno muestra la imagen que le pertenece.

```
$( "#BrazosE" ).change(function() {
  $('#imgBrazosEnteros').css("display","block");
  $('#imgBrazosEnteros').css("transition","1s");
});
```

Esto lo que me hace que cuando `#BazosE` cambia su estado me muestra la imagen, pero la idea es que al volver a pulsar vuelva a su estado habitual la imagen que es `display:none`

Comment: cada vez que cambie detecta su estado con `.is()` y haz lo acorde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He encontrado la respuesta

```
$('#BrazosE').change(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#imgBrazosEnteros').css("display","none");
      $('#imgBrazosEnteros').css("transition","1s");
    }
    else{
      $('#imgBrazosEnteros').css("display","block");
      $('#imgBrazosEnteros').css("transition","1s");
    }
});
```

**Otro método**

```
$('#BrazosE').change(function() { $('#imgBrazosEnteros').toggle() });
```

Comment: Perfecto, ahora que tienes la respuesta publicada, para mejorarla has de añadir un poco de epxlicacion de como funciona el metodo ìs()` y el metodo `toggle()`. busca en la docu y añade lo necesario para que futuros usuarios lo entiendan ^^  Pasadas 48h podrás marcar tu respuesta como  aceptada.

Comment: Gracias! @lois6b lo haré